# Mouse click event pygame

Tags: python, pygame

If you hold the mouse button, it counts that you are still clicking. I want to fix it so that when you click once, it counts once.

```py
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
ev = pygame.event.get()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
w = 800
h = 600
ScreenDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tap Simulator')
while True: # main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    clock.tick(30)
    handled = False
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and not handled:
        print("click!")
        handled = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event instead of `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`:

```py
run = True
while run: # main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1: # 1 == left button
                print("click!")
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

[`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) returns a list of Boolean values ​​that represent the state (`True` or `False`) of all mouse buttons. The state of a button is `True` as long as a button is held down.

The `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs once when you click the mouse button and the `MOUSEBUTTONUP` event occurs once when the mouse button is released.
The [`pygame.event.Event()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object has two attributes that provide information about the mouse event. `pos` is a tuple that stores the position that was clicked. `button` stores the button that was clicked. Each mouse button is associated a value. For instance the value of the attributes is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for the left mouse button, middle mouse button, right mouse button, mouse wheel up respectively mouse wheel down. When multiple keys are pressed, multiple mouse button events occur. Further explanations can be found in the documentation of the module [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't check for a mouse click explicitly, but you *can* check for the mouse button being pressed down (`event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`) or released (`event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP`).

```py
click_count = 0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            click_count += 1
```

Since `event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP` evaluates to `True` only when the mouse button is released, holding the mouse button down will not increment `click_count`.